# Trouble sorting numbers from smallest to largest in an array

Tags: java, arrays

This is one of my first posts on here so I am not sure if I am posting this correctly. But I need help trying to put the population of the states in order from smallest to largest that comes from a separate file. All the program is outputting is the states in alphabetical order. The file is set up like below.

**Expected input:**

```
Alabama,4779736
Alaska,710231
Arizona,6392017
```

**Class that attempts to sort:**

```
public class Inorder {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintWriter prw = new PrintWriter("outfile.txt");
        File f = new File("census2010.txt");
        if (!f.exists()) {
            System.out.println("f does not exist ");
        }
        Scanner infile = new Scanner(f);
        infile.useDelimiter("[\t|,|\n|\r]+");
        final int MAX = 50;
        int[] myarray = new int[MAX];
        String[] statearray = new String[MAX];
        int fillsize;

        fillsize = fillarray(myarray, statearray, infile);

        printarray(myarray, fillsize, prw);
        sortarray(myarray, statearray, fillsize);

    }

    public static int fillarray(int[] num, String[] states, Scanner infile) {

        int retcnt = 0;
        for (int count = 0; count < 50; count++) {

            int pop;
            String state;
            state = infile.next();
            pop = infile.nextInt();
            System.out.println(state + " " + pop + " ");
            states[retcnt] = state;
            num[retcnt] = pop;
            retcnt++;

        }
        return (retcnt);

    }

    public static void printarray(int[] num, int fillsize, PrintWriter prw) {
        for (int counts = 0; counts < fillsize; counts++) {
            System.out.println("For the position [" + counts
                    + "] the value is " + num[counts]);
            prw.println("For the position [" + counts + "] the value is "
                    + num[counts]);
        }
        return;
    }

    public static void sortarray(int[] poparray, String[] statearray,
            int fillsize) {

        for (int fill = 0; fill < fillsize - 1; fill = fill + 1) {

            for (int compare = fill + 1; compare < fillsize; compare++) {

                if (poparray[compare] < poparray[fill]) {
                    int poptemp = poparray[fill];
                    poparray[fill] = poparray[compare];
                    poparray[compare] = poptemp;
                    // do I need something here?
                    String statetemp = statearray[fill];
                    statearray[fill] = statearray[compare];
                    statearray[compare] = statetemp;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have two arrays, but only one, containing instances of State objects, having a name and a population. And then you can use Arrays.sort() to sort this array using the standard algorithm, without having to write your own. Also learn the Java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: Your comparison criterion is `poparray[compare] < poparray[fill]`.  Is that sorting on what you think it is?

Comment: I believe that my problem is the sorting array. My prof. said that we need to use two arrays.

Comment: Should I not use two arrays?

Comment: Maybe you can form a study group with a classmate?  [search for census2010](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=census2010)

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I am new to this site.

Comment: Its an online class anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program **already is** sorting the array in ascending order of population.

You are just not seeing it.

In your main, you print the arrays and then sort:

```
printarray (myarray, fillsize, prw);
sortarray(myarray, statearray, fillsize);
```

Instead, try sorting and only then printing:

```
sortarray(myarray, statearray, fillsize);
printarray (myarray, fillsize, prw);
```

You'll see your program is correct.

<sup>**Tip:**
You can use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myarray));` to print arrays easily.</sup>

Comment: Thats all it was!! I just had to move the sortarray about the print array. Thank you! I would give you a vote but I can't because I am a newbie

Comment: That's no problem at all! I'm glad I could help!